# Blank Page after deploying ASP.NET Core with reactjs application on IIS

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I deployed the application to IIS on my Windows 10 machine. But when I open the application in my browser, the page stays blank. If I run the application in the debugger, everything works fine.

The code is basically the unchanged code from the VS template. I just added some controllers and models. The .NET Core hosting bundle is installed on the machine.

The Microsoft documentation did not help in this case.

The browser developer tools console returns the following:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoYcM.png)

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
                     modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\ApplicationXYZ.exe" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
                hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I checked the Startup.cs. But it looks good to me:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews ();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles (configuration =>
                 {
                      configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
                 });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor ();
        services.Configure<DbConfig> (Configuration.GetSection ("DB"));
        services.AddTransient<IDbContext, DbContext> ();
    }

    public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment ())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler ("/Error");
            app.UseHsts ();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection ();
        app.UseStaticFiles ();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles ();

        app.UseRouting ();

        app.UseEndpoints (endpoints =>
            {
                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute (
                     name: "default",
                     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                 // endpoints.MapFallbackToController ("Index", "Home");
            });

        app.UseSpa (spa =>
               {
                   spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                   if (env.IsDevelopment ())
                   {
                        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer (npmScript: "start");
                   }
               });
    }
}
```

I would be very thankful for tips that will lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you install rewrite module in IIS?

Comment: Not yet. Is it necessary to install rewrite module?

Comment: Yes, is it necessary or the front-end with react or angular not work.